# Topology: Isolated Point?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question on [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point)'s example of an isolated point.

$X = \{a,b\}, \tau = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$

$a$ is an isolated point.

How is the point isolated if it is included in the neighborhood $X$?

Comment: Since $X$ is an open set in any topology, are you thinking that there are no isolated points, ever? As the wiki says, a  point $x\in S$ is "isolated in $S$" if and only if there exists an open set $O$ such that $O\cap S=\{x\}$. In this case, $a$ is isolated in $X$ as witnessed by the open set $O=\{a\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any point is included in $X$ so that's not a distinguishing feature.

A point $x$ is isolated (in $X$) if it forms an open set by itself, i.e. $\{x\} \in \tau$. The same holds for isolated points in a subset: we give the subset the subspace topology and a singleton that's open in the susbpace topology is called isolated (in that subset).

It's isolated because for no set $A$ we have $x \in \overline{A}$ unless $x \in A$ so the points is not "close" to any set that it's not already in.